# Which is the fastest way to find out if two strings are fuzzy? [Not another Levenshtein post]

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, performance, fuzzy-search

I want to compare two strings and determine if there is a minimum similarity between them, let's say, if they're 70% or more equal. I don't need to know the exact similarity, just if they are similar over a certain percentage.
Example:

The black cat smiles

The black cat cries

I know I can use Levenshtein distance to find out this, but it is too slow. I need to do millions of comparisons, so I just want to pre-filter those who are above of a certain percentage, and only in this, perform the levenhstein algorithm.
Until now, I am splitting the strings in words {the, black, cat, smiles} {the, black, cat, cries} and doing a intersection. But split is too slow.
If I want to compare 10000 sentences against a memory of 10000 sentences, split can take minutes, and I need to do this in seconds (no more than 1 minute).
I'm doing the operations on the ram memory, not in a DB.
Is there a way to solve this situation? Would it faster to use a DB, like SQL?
Some information would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
This is my code to prefiltering in vb.net

```
 Public Function CompareSegments(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Decimal
            Dim Percentagem As Double = 0
            ' Return 0
            Try
                '-----------------------------
                '------ IMPROVEMENT!!!!!!-----  MORE FILTERING
                '----------------------------
                If s2.Length / s1.Length > 1.6 Or s2.Length / s1.Length < 0.6 Then 'filtering by length comparison. If their lenghts are too much different, they aren't compared. We save some seconds.
                    Return 0
                End If
                Dim NumPalavrasNovas As Integer
                Dim MatrizPalavras1(), MatrizPalavras2() As String
                Dim separador() As String = {" "} 
                MatrizPalavras1 = s1.Split(separador, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                MatrizPalavras2 = s2.Split(separador, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                ' Dim Intersecao As IEnumerable(Of String) = MatrizPalavras1.Intersect(MatrizPalavras2) 
                If MatrizPalavras1.Length > MatrizPalavras2.Length Then
                    NumPalavrasNovas = MatrizPalavras1.Length 
                Else
                    NumPalavrasNovas = MatrizPalavras2.Length 
                End If
                If NumPalavrasNovas <> 0 Then

                    ' Dim j = Intersecao.ToList()
                    ' Percentagem = Intersecao.Count / NumPalavrasNovas
                    Percentagem = Intersect(MatrizPalavras1.ToList, MatrizPalavras2.ToList) / NumPalavrasNovas
                Else
                    Percentagem = 0
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Return Percentagem
        End Function
```

Comment: Are you looking for _different words_ vs. _equal words_ or more _different characters_ vs. _equal characters_? Is a string with a  _missing_ word still similar? Is your memory of 10000 sentences constant?

Comment: I'm also interested in this problem. For now, I found **local sensitivity hashing**. I have dictionary with ~100K words and want to do some precomputation/cutoff before making 100K Levinstain runs. Please, post updates in the case you find something interesting.

Comment: Is more like equal complete words. For example:

Comment: Is more like equal complete words. For example: the black cat <-> the white cat --- for me is the same comparison that : the white cat <-> the white cats.   I'm looking for a fast way to discard strings (sentences) that are not fuzzy enough (the 2.º example is a fuzzy of 66,6% comparing words, comparing with levenhstein is 92% fuzzy) My memory is not constant, but i want to fight with big ones, small ones are not a problem

Comment: google knowas many answers if you ask for _near duplicate detection_

Comment: “too slow” is actually pretty vague. Are you sure you have optimised your distance algorithm to the max? Using some tricks you can squeeze out *quite a lot* of performance – using Myers’ bit vector variant with the Ukkonen trick can yield a speedup in the order of 60-fold (if I remember correctly). And if you need to calculate this for many (relatively short) strings, then you can parallelise these comparisons, getting another speedup of ~4–8-fold on modern desktop machines/laptops. Getting the same amount of speedup using pre-filtering is possible, but as you’ve seen it’s not trivial either.

Comment: See the edit I did, to see my code, please. Did yo think I can improve this algorithm?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph , I don't know how to implement your advices about Myers' bit vector. In fact, I was seeing about in the internet and it's something that seems to complicated for me. Can you point up something for me in c# or vb.net? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Porkopek I’m not sure that there’s a .NET implementation available, but much to my surprise I actually did find a [Java implementation](http://vaadin.com/download/release/7.3/7.3.6/docs/api/com/google/gwt/dev/util/editdistance/MyersBitParallelEditDistance.html). Maybe that can be translated easily? There’s also a C++ implementation [in the SeqAn library](http://docs.seqan.de/seqan/1.4.1/SPEC_Myers.html). Otherwise you’d unfortunately have to go to the papers, understand the explanation, and implement it from scratch, I’m afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general hints:

You face the typical trade-off between accuracy and speed: if you can live with some errors you can get much higher speed.

With possible errors you should decide if you can tolerate false positives (string seems equal but isn't) or false negatives (string seems different but isn't). This will influence the choices (see below).

You should store your "memory" in a data structure which is searchable as efficient/ fast as possible. Look for a O(log n) searchable data structure like `SortedSet` or `SortedDictionary`or `SortedList`. If you need to change your memory often, the insert operation should be O(log n) which rules out `SortedList`. If you want to search for a *range* e.g. similartites you should go with `SortedSet` or a homegrown binary tree.

You should transform your incoming string in a form which is comparable and searchable as fast as possible. For example, it is very fast to transform words into a "hash" if done correctly. You may do it like this:

The String "ABC" is transformed into an `int` hash with:

```
int hash = 'A' + 'B' << 8 + 'C' << 16;
```

Very high speed, but some errors (there are other strings which result in the same hash)

With these ideas you could get a result very fast:

```
int hash = 0;
int shift = 0;
foreach(char c in incomingString)
{
    if( c _is whitespace_)
    { 
         // walk binary tree and see if the next word matches
         hash = 0;
         shift = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        hash += c.ToInt32() << shift;
        shift = (shift+8)%24;
    }
}
```

This is fast because it uses only add (1 cycle) and shift (1 cycle) operations, e.g. about 2 cycles per character.

If you want it faster, use the first 2 or 3 (or N) charcters per word only. If you want it more accurate, increase shift and/or store hash in a `long`.

This assumes that you transformed your *memory* into a binary tree of hash-lists, (one hash per word) which allows you to walk through the tree and find out if the incoming sequence of words (hashes) is part of your memory and stop the whole comparison after the first mismatch is found.

If you're not after *the first mismatch* but the *distance* between sentences, you could do a Lewenshtein-like alkorithm on the hashes.

Comment: I have to study your answer, thank you very much. I'll return with doubts

Answer (score 1):

Look at this paper:

[Detecting Near-Duplicates in Large-Scale Short Text Databases](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci2531/papers/duplicateshorttext.pdf)

> **Abstract.** Near-duplicates are abundant in short text databases. Detecting and eliminating them is of great importance. SimFinder
>   proposed in this paper is a fast algorithm to identify all
>   near-duplicates in large-scale short text databases. An ad hoc term
>   weighting scheme is employed to measure each term’s dis- criminative
>   ability. A certain number of terms with higher weights are seletect as
>   features for each short text. SimFinder generates several fingerprints
>   for each text, and only texts with at least one fingerprint in common
>   are compared with each other. An optimization procedure is employed in
>   SimFinder to make it more efficient. Experiments indicate that
>   SimFinder is an effective solution for short text duplicate detection
>   with almost linear time and storage complexity. Both precision and
>   recall of SimFinder are promising